# Maven simply replace 1 dependency in a remote repository

Tags: java, maven

First of all I want to say that I'm completely new to maven. So here is my question:

I just forked an open-source project which uses maven(let's call it project A). In the pom.xml there is a remote repository defined(maintained by the original authors of project A) and it grabs a couple of .jar files from there because they are dependencies. I adjusted something in the project I forked, and everything works fine, I can compile it and run it.

My problem is though that I just discovered I have to change something in one of the dependencies, luckily that dependency is also open-source, so I forked that too and made the needed adjustments(project B, also a maven project) and compiled it, everything worked fine so far. The problem I have now is: how do I tell maven that it has to grab my adjusted "project B", but still grab the rest of the dependencies from the remote repository when building project A?

I tried to use the "system" scope for the dependency, but that didn't work since it just doesn't include "project B" in the .jar anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cut a new release of the changed library with a new version. Then it will automatically pick it up whereever it can find it.

If you can not cut an official release you can build it locally and as a bonus install it in a repository manager.

And do NOT use system scope.

Comment: Thanks, this helped, how I did it was building the dependency with another version number, and used that in the pom.xml. At first I still said it couldn't find it, so I placed the resulting .jar in my local repository. That fixed it :)

Comment: Then you should accept my answer ;-) btw. if you build the jar with mvn clean install it will put it in your repo already .. no need to place it there manually